# Number of characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

By theorem (it takes too much space to write their proof so I just show it's conclusion),
characteristic polynomial of a matirx $A \in M_{2*2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ is
$$f(t)=t^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)t+\det(A)$$

Then determine the number of distinct characteristic polynomial.
The answer is 4 and the reason is that the coefficient could be 0 or 1.
I can't figure out what the coefficient is. It means $\operatorname{tr}(A)$? Then why it could be 0 or 1?

Comment: This makes no sense. There must be some information you have left out.

Comment: I'm with @HaraldHanche-Olsen. Is it possible that this is for matrices over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I left some information and added it now, $M_{2*2}(Z)$.

Comment: Having entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't look to me like it restricts the problem to the extent you want it to. Is there some restriction on the values of the determinant?

Comment: Um... I don't think so. There are no more restrictions on the determinant.

Comment: It might that your field is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and not the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane You're right! Sorry, I didn't know the difference between them. What is $Z_2$ and how can I solve this?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_1(t)=t^2$$
$$f_2(t)=t(t+1)$$
$$f_3(t)=t^2+1$$
$$f_4(t)=t^2+t+1$$